# Error message on function in Xcode 6.3 beta 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have just opened up the newest Xcode beta (8.3 beta 2) and am in the process of converting my code to Swift 1.2. I have ran into an issue with a particular line of code that I can't figure out the solution to.

Basically I am getting the error: `Objective-C method 'textFieldShouldReturn:' provided by method 'textFieldShouldReturn' conflicts with optional requirement method 'textFieldShouldReturn' in protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'`

That is on this code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        budgetNameText.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Please show some more context.

Comment: I noticed that protocol has changed - method must now return a Boolean value like so:
@IBAction func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool
    {
        budgetNameText.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your error-message, there is already a method called like your method. So your problem is, that in the `UITextFieldDelegate`, there is also a method called [`textFieldShouldReturn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:). So you need to rename your `IBAction` method to something else.

This is the method the delegate provides:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```